# Rails - new data shows only in development mode can't figure out how to migrate it to production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been following Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial. I am at the beginning of chapter 8 with a brand new login page. At the end of Chapter 7 i had switched from the default WEBrick server to puma. Everything worked fine, i had the same result in production as i had in development mode. However, at the beginning of chapter 8 a login page was added so a session controller was created, added `GET/POST/DELETE /login` to routes.rb, updated `session_controller_test.rb` and created a `sessions/new.html.erb` for the login form. The login form shows in the development mode but i can't get it show in production mode. I tried heroku reset, heroku run `rake db:migrate`. I restarted the server. I added two new users to the app and ran rails c production but no users were found. heroku logs result: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sessions")`:

```
rails routes: Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
   users_new GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
        root GET    /                         static_pages#home
        help GET    /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
       about GET    /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
     contact GET    /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
      signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
             POST   /signup(.:format)         users#create
       login GET    /login(.:format)          sessions#new
             POST   /login(.:format)          sessions#create
      logout DELETE /logout(.:format)         sessions#destroy
       users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

I am new to coding. I have been trying to figure this out but it beats me. Any idea, please?

Comment: did you commit your code and push to heroku?

Comment: yes i did, i was in a branch but i merged back to master and i pushed it to heroku, i reloaded the server but it still says it can't find the login page, besides that all other pages show up however i noticed that the the only one user i created in development mode with WEBrick does not exist in production mode with puma and the two users i created in production mode with puma does not show up in development mode

Comment: Please format your code blocks and add your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: please view it on github at https://github.com/borivo/copy_sample_app this is the best way i think thanks!

Comment: i just checked the updates on bitbucket and realized that none of the pushes got through i don't understand how it could happen i didn't get any error messages though....however i redone all the push on bitbucket and to heroku and finally the login page shows up....i don't understand at what point and why my pushes stoped getting through but i learned a good lesson though...